# Azure Custom Tag Policy, Exclude resource type

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I did an azure custom policy that discover object not compliant, with custom missing tag, on my subscription.

I got to much error from this policy becouse it discover also oms agent, extension etc..

Here the json:

```
    {
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "field": "tags['TAG1']",
          "exists": false
        },
        {
          "field": "tags['TAG2']",
          "exists": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
  }
```

it search all resources and audit it if they are not with that tag.

Is possibile to specified exclusion for specific resources type? For example Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can mention all the resource types in "notEquals" operator for which you do not want to check for tags.

```
{
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "notEquals": "Microsoft.Security/assessments"
          },
          {
            "field": "type",
            "notEquals": "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachines"
          },
          {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "tags['TAG1']",
                "exists": false
              },
              {
                "field": "tags['TAG2']",
                "exists": false
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "audit"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `"mode": "indexed"` instead of `"mode": "All"` will only match resources that support location and tags.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#resource-manager-modes